# Ошибка сегментирования, классы и конструкторы

Tags: c++

добрый день!
изучаю с++ по книге стивена праты
написал класс

```
#ifndef COW_H_
#define COW_H_

class Cow {
private:
    char name[20];
    char * hobby;
    double weight;
public:
    Cow();
    Cow(const char *nm, const char *ho, double wt);
    Cow(const Cow & c);
    ~Cow();
    Cow & operator=(const Cow & c);
    void ShowCow() const;
};


#endif
```

методы класса следующие:

```
#include "cow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

Cow::Cow()
{
    strcpy(name, "NONE");
    hobby = new char[5];
    strcpy(hobby, "NONE");
    weight = 0.0;
}

 Cow::Cow(const char *nm, const char *ho, double wt)
{
    if(nm == nullptr)
    {
        strcpy(name, "NONE");   
    }
    else
    {
        strncpy(name, nm, 19);
        name[19] = '\0';
    }
    if(ho == nullptr)
    {
        hobby = new char[5];
        strcpy(hobby, "NONE");  
    }
    else
    {
        int len = strlen(ho);
        hobby = new char[len+1];
        strcpy(hobby, ho);
    }
    weight = wt;
}

Cow::Cow(const Cow & c)
{
    strcpy(name, c.name);
    delete [] hobby;
    hobby = new char[strlen(c.hobby) + 1];
    strcpy(hobby, c.hobby);
    weight = c.weight;
}


void Cow::ShowCow() const
{
    std::cout << "Name: " << name 
    << std::endl << "Hobby: " << hobby 
    << std::endl << "Weight: " << weight 
    << std::endl;
}

Cow::~Cow()
{
    delete [] hobby;
}


Cow & Cow::operator=(const Cow & c)
{
    if(this == &c)
    {
        return *this;   
    }
    strcpy(name, c.name);
    delete [] hobby;
    hobby = new char[strlen(c.hobby) + 1];
    strcpy(hobby, c.hobby);
    weight = c.weight;
    return *this;
}
```

к нему написана программа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cow.h"

int main()
{
    Cow one;
    Cow two("COwjsldnfsdn,sdnf,sndfsdmds","Music", 120.0);
    std::cout << "one: " << std::endl;
    one.ShowCow();
    std::cout << "two:" << std::endl;
    two.ShowCow();
    std::cout << "Three" << std::endl;
    Cow three = two;
    three.ShowCow();
    three = two;
    three.ShowCow();
    Cow four(one);
    std::cout << "Four = one:" << std::endl;
    four.ShowCow();
    four = two;
    std::cout << "Four = two:" << std::endl;
    four.ShowCow();
    return 0;
}
```

падает в следующей строке:

Cow three = two;

one: 
   Name: NONE
   Hobby: NONE
   Weight: 0
   two:
   Name: COwjsldnfsdn,sdnf,s
   Hobby: Music
   Weight: 120
   Three
   Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)

В чем я накосячил?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В конструкторе

```
Cow::Cow(const Cow & c)
{
    strcpy(name, c.name);
    delete [] hobby;
    hobby = new char[strlen(c.hobby) + 1];
    strcpy(hobby, c.hobby);
    weight = c.weight;
}
```

Вот эта строчка

```
delete [] hobby;
```

не нужна. Вы же только *создаете* объект, в нем еще память не выделялась, удалять вам нечего! Уберите эту строку.

(А вот в операторе присваивания вы все делаете верно, там она нужна, там вы присваиваете уже существующему объекту, и `hobby` - указатель на уже выделенную память...)

Comment: спасибо, все заработало!

Comment: Не сомневался :) Ну, если все OK, закрывайте вопрос, пометив ответ как принятый...

Comment: через 7 мин, раньше никак